# Unable to delete files inside the directory in java

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I know this issue is very common but I don't know why its not deleting the file.

here is my code below:

```
String newRoot = rootFile.toString();
            File[] transFiles = new File(newRoot).listFiles();
            for(File file : transFiles){
                destFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("Test/Raw");
                FileInputStream fisFile = new FileInputStream(file);
                destFtpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), fisFile);
                if(file.exists())
                {
                    file.delete();
                }
                else
                    return;
                fisFile.close();
            }
```

Appreciate all of your answers thank you!..

Comment: did `if` executed ?

Comment: yes, its executed and no errors found but the file is not deleted.

Comment: How do you know the if boolean test was true? There's no println within the block?

Comment: Well, unfortunately i tried it again today and the if is not working anymore and also i used `FTPClient` `destFtpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` its directing me on this statement.

Comment: It's possible that `destFtpClient.storeFile` still has the file open.  Perhaps use [`Files.delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) (or `Files.deleteOfExists`) instead, at least it throws a `IOException`

Comment: Voting to close as a non-reproducible problem

Comment: May be your program doesn't have permissions to delete the files. Try running the program with root/admin privileges, or change the permissions of the file.